# Accessing images stored in different files in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, symlink

I have an admin and a user portal. Admin uploads the member image which has to be displayed in user portal. Both admin and user portal are present in different files. I tried "php artisan storage:link", the image does get stored under public/storage/image but it does not gets displayed in user portal. Any solutions would be helpful.

```
$member->image = $request->image;

        if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extenstion = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extenstion;
            $file->move('storage/image', $filename);
            $member->image = $filename;
        } 
      $member->save();

   <img src="/storage/image/{{ $member->image }}" width="150" height="150"/>
```

How should I specify the path for this in user portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asset helper function to generate the URL to the image. This should work if you have run the `php artisan storage:link` command to create a symbolic link from the public/storage directory to the storage/app/public directory.

Here is how you can use the asset function to generate the URL to the image:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/image/'.$member->image) }}" width="150" height="150" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use the Storage facade to generate the URL to the image, like this:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url('image/'.$member->image) }}" width="150" height="150" />
```

These solutions should allow you to display the image in the portal.

Comment: Image is uploaded by admin and uploaded image is displayed to user, they are in complete different folders. Does this method work for this. (I tried but it doesn't display image in user)

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to check your file path is where for directory.
you can confirm storage link path after move public.

```
$ cd /var/www/html/public
$ ls -la
$ storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public // example
```

and then, your load file path is correct ?

for example, if you want to load file under
`storage/app/public/hoge.png`,
you can load like
<img src="{{ asset("storage/hoge.png") }}" >

try those.

Comment: the image is stored under admin folders - storage/image and I want to display under users view blade. Is it possible?

Comment: you can load files if you set views/*.blade.php. because storage link has effect all view files. if you use chrome, open developer screen and find your image source code and also can you show how your image path and errors?

Comment: image path - <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/image/1670399631.jpg" width="150" height="150">   error - 404 not found.

Comment: thanks. check the file you want to show is under ```storage/app/public/image/1670399631.jpg```
and then , i don't know where is your admin folder. if your admin folder is ```storage/app/public/image/admin```, you can access ``` asset("storage/image/admin/1670399631.jpg") ```

Comment: under admin folder it is there.. but not under users folder.

Comment: Admin and User are 2 different Visual Studio files!!

Comment: I don't make sense your application structure... can you show tree structure at your main question field here ?

Comment: maybe do you use two laravel applications each admin and user?
like admin/laravelapp and user/laravelapp at same develop structure.

Comment: Like I have 2 logins (completely 2 different VS) for admin and user. Here admin uploads the images of alumni members which must be visible for the users in their cover page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250209/discussion-between-preethi-shetty-and-takuma-bo).

Comment: Where you are facing this issue in live server or localhost???

Comment: Localhost.. actually the approach was wrong because I'm working with 2 different laravel applications.